# Why is it valid to call a void function within Assert.assertNotNull?

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, assert, assertion

Take for example the following pseudo-code,

`Assert.assertNotNull(cut.func())`

Where `cut` is a **non-null** class under test, and `func()` is some function that returns void.

Furthermore, assuming `func()` does not throw any errors this will result in a **valid** assertion.

Since it [isn't possible to set an object to be null from within itself in Java / Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18293626/9017639),  (i.e. `func()` cannot set `cut` to `null`), why is it valid to call void functions within **non-null** assertions?

Is it simply because `void` is not the same as `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's `void` return type is mapped to the [`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/index.html) object in Kotlin, and `Unit` is not `null`.

```
val x = System.out.println("") // void Java method

println(x == null) // "false"
println(x == Unit) // "true"
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have read the documentation first.  

As a quick follow-up, is it good practice to perform an `Assert.assertNotNull` on said functions to ensure they return `Unit`, or is `Assert.assertEquals(Unit::class, cut.func()::class)` better?

Comment: No need to check the return value of a void method. Just need to check that it doesn't throw any exceptions, and that it performs its intended operations.